# Error when I try to create web service client

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl, wsimport

I have a problem when I try to generate the web service client 
this is the address

> `*https://apphom.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl*`

I tried the "eclipse" and nothing, following error

```
*> The service definition selected is invalid.*
```

Also I tried by wsimport but it gave me this error

```
*> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
> su   n.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable
> to find valid c   ertification path to requested target      Failed to
> read the WSDL document: https://apphom.correios.com.br/SigepMasterJPA/
> AtendeClienteService/AtendeCliente?wsdl, because 1) could not find the
> document;   /2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of
> the document is not   <wsdl:definitions>.  
>       [ERROR] failed.noservice=Could not find wsdl:service in the provided WSDL(s):      At least one WSDL with at least one service
> definition needs to be provided.  
>   
>   
>         Failed to parse the WSDL.*
```

I imported the digital certificate and in jvm and in windows,
I have no idea what's happening, Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/suncertpathbuilderexception-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requested-target/) provides a step by step solution for this issue.

Comment: So do I need to be running a application server as weblogic? but What the impact with generate web service client

I did this before I tried to generate the clients

    

***> keytool -import -trustcacerts -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit
> -noprompt -alias correios1 -file correios1.crt***

this should work perfectly, however it isn´t

Comment: You dont need to have an application server running. You can execute this from command prompt. Just need to set the jdk path.                set path=D:\Java1.6\jdk1.6.0_20\bin